# How can I remove the div has the same url and keep only value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have HTML like :

```
<ul id='myul'>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link1">Link1</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link2">Link2</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link4">Link4</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link1">Link1</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can see href = `http://domain.com/link1` is repeated. So, I want remove one of theme, and keep only one. That mean I have HTML like :

```
<ul id='myul'>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link1">Link1</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link2">Link2</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://domain.com/link4">Link4</a>
    <span>something1</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I do that with jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the first way that came to mind:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var urls = {};
    $("#myul a").each(function() {
        if (this.href in urls)
            $(this).closest("li").remove();
        else
            urls[this.href] = true;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CBhF6/

That is, loop over all of the anchor elements within the ul, and test if the current one has an href that you've already seen - if so delete it, otherwise make a note of the href.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  $( "li" ).get( -1 )

as long as it is the last one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var lnkHash = {};

$('li > a').each(function(){

    if(lnkHash[this.href])
    {
      $(this).closest('li').remove();
    } else
    {
      lnkHash[this.href] = 1;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c4zVk/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var url = [];
$("#myul").find("li").each(function(){
    var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    if(url.indexOf(href) >= 0){
        $(this).remove();
    }
    else{
        url.push(href);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/Hjv2d/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myul a').each(function(){
        var currHref = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#myul').find('a[href="' +currHref +'"]').each(function(index){
            if(index > 0) {
                $(this).closest('li').remove(); 
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rKpaK/2/

Comment: Rather than having a nested `.each()` loop with an if test in the inner one, couldn't you just say `$('#myul').find('a[href="' +currHref +'"]').slice(1).closest('li').remove();`? http://jsfiddle.net/rKpaK/3/